# How to duplicate a record and change its start/end date based on the start/end on a joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Savings table where each row shows a software module, a stakeholder, and the amount of time that the module saves the stakeholder by automating one of their tasks. Each row shows how much time the task takes to do manually vs automatically, how often the task is performed (eg 2x per week), and an effective start and end date. For example:

| Module | Stakeholder | Manual Task Time (min) | Automated Task Time (min) | Times Task Performed | Frequency | Effective Start | Effective End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 Automation | John Doe | 1440 | 0.5 | 4 | Week | 4/6/2023 | 8/1/2023 |
| Task 2 Automation | Jane Smith | 480 | 1 | 1 | Day | 10/29/2022 | 10/1/2023 |
| Task 3 Automation | Billy | 2880 | 1 | 1 | Month | 6/1/2022 | 12/1/2023 |
| Task 4 Automation | John Doe | 260 | 1 | 3 | Week | 9/1/2023 | 12/1/2023 |
| Task 5 Automation | John Doe | 300 | 2 | 2 | Week | 4/1/2022 | 7/1/2022 |

This table will be joined to a Stakeholder table that includes their name, base salary, and an effective start and end date. If a stakeholder's salary changes, a new record is created for them, and the most current record is indicated by a NULL in the "Effective End" date field. For example:

| Stakeholder | Base Salary | Effective Start | Effective End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 60,000 | 1/1/2022 | 8/1/2023 |
| John Doe | 80,000 | 8/1/2023 |  |
| Jane Smith | 100,000 | 10/1/2022 |  |
| Billy | 95,000 | 1/1/2022 |  |

After joining these two tables, a few calculated fields will be added. These fields will convert the base salary to an hourly rate, and calculate how much time and labor costs were saved by the module during the effective date range.

But if a stakeholder has a salary change between the Savings "Effective Start" and "Effective End" dates, then both salaries need to be applied. For example, with "Task 1 Automation", the salary used in the calculation needs to be 60,000 until 8/1/2023, then 80,000 from 8/1/2023 until 12/1/2023. So the row needs to appear twice, with its "Effective Start" and "Effective End" dates updated accordingly. The output table should look like this:

| Module | Stakeholder | Manual Task Time (min) | Automated Task Time (min) | Times Task Performed | Frequency | Effective Start | Effective End | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 Automation | John Doe | 1440 | 0.5 | 4 | Week | 4/6/2023 | 8/1/2023 | 60,000 |
| Task 1 Automation | John Doe | 1440 | 0.5 | 4 | Week | 8/1/2023 | 12/1/2023 | 80,000 |
| Task 2 Automation | Jane Smith | 480 | 1 | 1 | Day | 10/29/2022 | 10/1/2023 | 100,000 |
| Task 3 Automation | Billy | 2880 | 1 | 1 | Month | 6/1/2022 | 12/1/2023 | 95,000 |
| Task 4 Automation | John Doe | 260 | 1 | 3 | Week | 9/1/2023 | 12/1/2023 | 80,000 |
| Task 5 Automation | John Doe | 300 | 2 | 2 | Week | 4/1/2022 | 7/1/2022 | 60,000 |

What's the best way to do this?

#### EDIT

A few records added to the first sample table, and the expected salary added to the last sample table, for clarification

#### Clarification notes

- Task 1 Automation -- Both salaries apply
- Task 4 Automation -- Only the later salary applies
- Task 5 Automation -- Only the earlier salary applies

The "Task 1 Automation" record should appear twice, because John Doe had a salary change in the middle of its effective date range. So the first copy should only include the slice of that date range where John Doe had a 60,000 salary. The second copy should only include the slice where John Doe had a 80,000 salary.

The "Task 4 Automation" record should only appear once with an 80,000 salary, because John Doe had a salary of 80,000 during the entire effective date range.

The "Task 5 Automation" record should only appear once with a 60,000 salary, because John Doe had a salary of 60,000 during the entire effective date range.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `JOIN`?

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure how a simple `JOIN` would solve it, but I may just be too inexperienced with SQL to see what I'm missing. I expanded my sample data and added some clarifying notes to my question

Comment: A common way to test for overlapping ranges is `(A.Start < B.End AND B.Start < A.End)` You can joint your two tables based on a matching `Stakeholder` and the preceding overlapping range test. For ranges with no end, you can use the `ISNULL()` function to provide an alternate "end-of-time" value like 9999-12-31.  The length of the overlap can be calculated as `LEAST(A.End, B.End) - GREATEST(A.STart, B.Start)`.  Give it a try. If you run into difficulties, post the SQL from your attempt as an update to your question for further assistance.

Comment: I answered a similar question involving overlapping ranges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586619/#77588637). Look at the join in the final query in that answer and try to do something similar. That post also shows alternate coding for the LEAST*() and GREATEST() functions.

Comment: Thank you @TN, this overlapping range test is exactly the logic I was looking for.

Comment: @Nick - For the given data, why would you expect a match between Task 1 (4/6/2023 - 8/1/2023) and John Doe at 80000 Base Salary (8/1/2023 - indefinite)? That combination has adjacent date ranges, but zero overlap. (This assumes *exclusive* end dates, which seems to be the case.) I am also unsure where the expected 12/1/2023 effective end is coming from in that result row. In Dale K's answer, that result row would be eliminated by changing the `>=` to a `>` in the join condition, which I believe is more correct.

Comment: @TN The error was in the EffectiveStart and EffectiveEnd dates in the Task 1 row of the first table was an error. The EffectiveEnd should have been 12/1/2023, not 8/1/2023. In the actual query, 12/1/2023 is today's date (`GETDATE()`).

Comment: @TN I think most of us wouldn't normally have the start date of the new salary = the end date of the old, we would normally add a day and then the equality would be different.

Comment: @DaleK I have found that *inclusive* start and *exclusive* end dates (or date/times) to be better arrangement when working with ranges - looking up a matching record, calculating durations, comparing ranges, and even checking for gaps. Think of the dates and as a moment in time at 00:00. It works particularly well with mixed date and date/time values, since you don't have to truncate. Only drawback I have found is that you  can't use `value BETWEEN start AND end`, instead testing explicitly for `value >= start and value < end`. I recommend it to anyone starting a new design.

Comment: @TN I agree that it makes queries easier to write, but from a data perspective it's not intuitive, because you always have to remember not to include the end date. This example is case in point, I had to think twice to realise that I should exclude the end date. I would rather store the actual end date then add a day for comparison. Personally I never use between, because that also is not intuitive. Clear code over clever code is my motto :) so that it's easy to work out what is happening years later.

Comment: That aside, so long as OP can follow and therefore adjust the join logic to suit then all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query solves your problem as asked. However it doesn't return `12/1/2023` for the second row as you have put in your desired results, but I cannot see where it should get it from either, so I suspect that is incorrect.

The key point you were missing was putting the date matching criteria in your join condition. Once you add that you get the rows you desire.

```
select
    s.[Module]
    , s.Stakeholder
    , s.ManualTaskMin
    , s.AutomatedTaskMin
    , s.TimesPerformed
    , EffectiveStart = iif(sh.EffectiveStart > s.EffectiveStart, sh.EffectiveStart, s.EffectiveStart)
    , EffectiveEnd = iif(sh.EffectiveEnd < s.EffectiveEnd, sh.EffectiveEnd, s.EffectiveEnd)
from #Stakeholder sh
join #Savings s
    on sh.Stakeholder = s.Stakeholder
    and s.EffectiveEnd >= sh.EffectiveStart
    and (s.EffectiveStart < sh.EffectiveEnd or sh.EffectiveEnd is null)
order by s.[Module];
```

Returns:

| Module | Stakeholder | ManualTaskMin | AutomatedTaskMin | TimesPerformed | EffectiveStart | EffectiveEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 Automation | John Doe | 1440 | 0.5 | 4 | 2023-04-06 | 2023-08-01 |
| Task 1 Automation | John Doe | 1440 | 0.5 | 4 | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| Task 2 Automation | Jane Smith | 480 | 1.0 | 1 | 2022-10-29 | 2023-10-01 |
| Task 3 Automation | Billy | 2880 | 1.0 | 1 | 2022-06-01 | 2023-12-01 |
| Task 4 Automation | John Doe | 260 | 1.0 | 3 | 2023-09-01 | 2023-12-01 |
| Task 5 Automation | John Doe | 300 | 2.0 | 2 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-07-01 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hqugEyK3)

Comment: This solves the problem, thank you @Dale K. You're right, that 12/1/2023 was put there by mistake.

Comment: Changing `>=` to `>` in the join condition would eliminate that row entirely, since it has adjacent date ranges, but zero overlap.  Adding another task savings row `('Task 1a Automation', 'John Doe', 1440, 0.5, 4, 'Week', '4/6/2023', '12/1/2023')` to the test, would show the split salary case. *That was the original data before edit #2  was applied to the question.*

Comment: @Nick - Could task effective end date ever be null? If so, the above join condition would need adjustment to allow that case. The `EffectiveEnd = iif(...)` calculation would also need tweaking to ensure correct handling of all null date cases - (date, date), (date, null), (null, date), and (null, null).

Comment: @TN Technically in the original tables they can potentially be null, but in effect no -- because before this part of the query (joining Solutions and Stakeholders), all nulls in the Stakeholders and Solutions tables get replaced with `GETDATE()` or the value in some other date field from a different part of the query (that isn't shown in this question/example). I was able to get @DaleK's query to work both with and without NULLs in the EffectiveEnd fields.